# Animate.css one letter of a word

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

I am trying to animate one letter of a word using animate.css.  The animate does not work in a span and I can not find any good information on this subject. How can I animate one letter of a word using animate.css?
Here is my code:

```css
.animated {
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated.infinite {
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes tada {
 from {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
 transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
 10%, 20% {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
 transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
}
 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
 transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
}
 40%, 60%, 80% {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
 transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
}
to {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
 transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
}
 @keyframes tada {
 from {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
 transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
 10%, 20% {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
 transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
}
 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
 transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
}
 40%, 60%, 80% {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
 transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
}
to {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
 transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
}
.tada {
 -webkit-animation-name: tada;
 animation-name: tada;
}
/********************************/
.ani-g{
 font-size: 36px;
 color: #66ccff;
}
.ani-en{
 color: #66ccff;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 8px;
 display: inline;
}
.ani-erate{
 color: #666666;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 8px;
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span class="ani-g animated infinite tada">G</span><span class="ani-en">EN</span><span class="ani-erate">ERATE THIS</span>
<h1 class="n-bitwise animated infinite tada">G</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a block level element for this animation. Just insert `display: inline-block;` for your `.animated` class and it should work!

```css
.animated {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  text-align: center;
}
@-webkit-keyframes tada {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  10%,
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes tada {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  10%,
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
.tada {
  -webkit-animation-name: tada;
  animation-name: tada;
}
/********************************/

.ani-g {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #66ccff;
}
.ani-en {
  color: #66ccff;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8px;
  display: inline;
}
.ani-erate {
  color: #666666;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span class="ani-g animated infinite tada">G</span><span class="ani-en">EN</span><span class="ani-erate">ERATE THIS</span>
<h1 class="n-bitwise animated infinite tada">G</h1>
```